# Problems uninstalling AWS Tools PowerShell Modules

Tags: powershell, aws-toolkit

I've previously had AWS tools installed but I was getting various alerts about having multiple versions installed etc. that I tried to remove them. I think I've removed the actual module folders at some point but I don't recall exactly what I've done tbh.

Anyway, I figured I could run the Uninstall-AWSToolsModule -Force to remove the lot and start again but that's giving me the errors below. Somehow, Windows thinks these modules are still installed. Any idea how I can clean up this mess?

```
c:\test\ > Uninstall-AWSToolsModule -force
Uninstalling AWS.Tools version 4.1.229
Uninstalling module AWS.Tools.AccessAnalyzer
Uninstall-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'AWS.Tools.AccessAnalyzer'.
Uninstalling module AWS.Tools.Account
Uninstall-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'AWS.Tools.Account'.
Uninstalling module AWS.Tools.ACMPCA
Uninstall-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'AWS.Tools.ACMPCA'.
Uninstalling module AWS.Tools.AlexaForBusiness
Uninstall-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'AWS.Tools.AlexaForBusiness'.
Uninstalling module AWS.Tools.Amplify
Uninstall-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'AWS.Tools.Amplify'.
Uninstalling module AWS.Tools.AmplifyBackend
Uninstall-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'AWS.Tools.AmplifyBackend'.
Uninstalling module AWS.Tools.AmplifyUIBuilder
Uninstall-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'AWS.Tools.AmplifyUIBuilder'.
Uninstalling module AWS.Tools.APIGateway
Uninstall-Package: No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'AWS.Tools.APIGateway'.
```

... and it goes on and on....